# Can't send Vert.x messages across network

Tags: java, hazelcast, vert.x

I am trying to send messages in clustered vert.x to other hosts. Running the following code twice on one computer works, but if I use two hosts it fails (message is not received). I use Vert.x 3.3.1 with Hazelcast. I appended the log of the slave side running on a separate host, where it does seem like they are finding and connecting to each other.

I am thankful for any input!

Worker

```
public class WorkerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Deployed " + getClass().getName());
    vertx.eventBus().<String> consumer("TEST_ADDRESS", this::doWork);
}
private void doWork(Message<String> msg) {
    String workItemString = msg.body();
    System.out.println("Got Work:" + workItemString);
}
}
```

Mainclass

```
public class Starter {
Vertx vertx;

public Starter(boolean slave) {
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
    options.setClustered(true);
    Future<Void> completer1 = Future.future();
    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            vertx = res.result();
            completer1.complete();
            System.out.println("Opened clustered vertx");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + res.cause() + ". Quitting now.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    });
    completer1.setHandler(new Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(AsyncResult<Void> event) {
            if (slave) {
                System.out.println("Deploying worker");
                vertx.deployVerticle(WorkerVerticle.class.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("publishing message");
                vertx.eventBus().publish("TEST_ADDRESS", "Test");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Example log of slave running on separate host

```
INFORMATION: [192.168.2.191]:5701 [dev] [3.6.3] Accepting socket connection from /192.168.2.3:55878
Jul 21, 2016 10:20:43 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFORMATION: [192.168.2.191]:5701 [dev] [3.6.3] Established socket connection between /192.168.2.191:5701 and /192.168.2.3:55878
Jul 21, 2016 10:20:44 AM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService
INFORMATION: [192.168.2.191]:5701 [dev] [3.6.3] 

Members [2] {
    Member [192.168.2.191]:5701 this
    Member [192.168.2.3]:5701
}
```

Comment: Are you running the vertx processes with the `-cluster` switch?

Comment: Starting the program like this: `java -jar vertxtest.jar -cluster`

Comment: Could you try telnet ip port from both host to the other one on port 5701? I know HZ reports it's connected but just to make sure...

Comment: Accessable from both hosts...

Comment: did you solve this at the end  @timmiotooltim ? I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Hazelcast is working properly (your logs show that both nodes discover themselves, because you have 2 members). What could be happening is that the hostname resolution on the host JVM is returning some internal IP address and then each node cannot connect to the others.

In order to specify the right device you can use the command:

```
java -jar vertxtest.jar -cluster -cluster-host <your.ip.address>
```

Please note that vert.x will pick a free port when starting the cluster so you should relax your firewall, or if you want to be more secure specify also which port can vert.x use (besides 5700 from hazelcast) with:

```
java -jar vertxtest.jar -cluster -cluster-host <your.ip> -cluster-port 5800
```

Comment: I am facing exact issue. do you have a code example to share that works in two different docker containers?